# you need to use a theme.appcompat

Tags: android

I'm not a developer. I have a problem while editing a google search widget. Google app crashes with this log: https://del.dog/bihagetole
What should i do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You must define the theme parent in your styles.xml file

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. This one does not have a action bar for example -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: As i said i'm not a developer. Could you tell me the path of  this file please?

Comment: If you are using android studio: App > Res > Values > Style.xml